# WP CSS & JS not Enqueuing

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am trying to get WordPress to use my CSS and JS files, but it does not seem to use them. My CSS works via the Custom CSS tab, but this is not ideal obviously. I have included my functions.php file code for reference. How can I fix this?

My PHP Code...

```
<?php

function test_script_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_style( "test", get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/test.css", array(), "1.0.0", "all" );
    wp_enqueue_script( "test", get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/test.js", array(), "1.0.0", true );
};

add_action( "wp_enqueue_scripts", "test_script_enqueue" );

function test_theme_setup() {

    add_theme_support("menus");

    register_nav_menu("primary", "Primary Test Nav");
    register_nav_menu("secondary", "Test Sidebar Nav");

}

add_action("init", "test_theme_setup");

add_theme_support("custom-background");
add_theme_support("custom-header");

function test_widget_setup() {

    register_sidebar(
        array(
            "name"  =>  "Sidebar",
            "id"    =>  "test-sidebar-1",
            "class" =>  "test-custom",
            "description" =>    "Test Sidebar",
            'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget'  => '</li>',
            'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>',
        )
    );

}

add_action("widgets_init","test_widget_setup");

?>
```

Comment: To better debug this, two suggestions: 
1. inspect your page and see if this test.css are included in your HTML; 
2. If so, are those CSS be overwritten? (because external CSS will has a different priority than putting then into Custom CSS input box;
3. I will also try to clear my WP cache and see if that's a caching issue.

Also, If you can provide an url to your page, that may be helpful

Comment: Can you check your CSS and JS in page source and Can you try to open that CSS and JS file by clicking and see, whether path is correct or not

Comment: Yes, that results in it saying it cannot find the files. Could this be a permissions issue, then? If not, what else could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue on my own. The path needed to have capital letters for the "JS" and "CSS" directories. The web host told me to put lower-case because of the way their Linux server was run, but they were wrong. They were confused when I made it work this way too.

Anyway, the issue has been solved. So if all else fails and you have the same problem, try using upper or lower case letters in the file paths in your functions.php!

Edited Code:

```
 wp_enqueue_style( "test", get_template_directory_uri() . "/CSS/test.css", array(), "1.0.0", "all" );
    wp_enqueue_script( "test", get_template_directory_uri() . "/JS/test.js", array(), "1.0.0", true );
```